# PHP Switching between sessions using session_name

Tags: php, session

So I'm trying to write 2 php sessions in the same script, but seems it doesn't work as I thought it will do.

The code:

```
// Start our first session with the name 's1'
session_name('s1');
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Foo';
session_write_close();

// Start our second session with the name 's2'
session_name('s2');
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Bar';
session_write_close();

// We now open our first session and print its value
session_name('s1');
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION['foo']);
```

It prints `Bar` were afaik it **should** print `Foo` since we openned session `s1`

#### Question:

What is the correct way *(I think using session_id is not a safe way of doing this)* to make it print `Foo`?

---

Also, if you write something like `$_SESSION['color'] = 'red';` in session `s2`, and you go ahead and print the whole `s1` session, you will see the key `color` there, it should not be there.

**Am I misusing sessions?**

Comment: do `var_dump($_SESSION)` at each stage. don't have access to php right now, but I'm guessing it just MERGES the loaded session with whatever's in $_SESSION at the time you call session_start(), so all the session work you did  in previous/different-named sessions just accumulates in $_SESSION.

Comment: @MarcB even if do `$_SESSION = [];` after each `session_write_close();` it does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved if you use session_id instead of session_name

```
// Start our first session with the name 's1'
session_name('s1');
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Foo';
session_write_close();

// Start our second session with the name 's2'
session_name('s2');
//session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Bar';
session_write_close();

// We now open our first session and print its value
session_name('s1');
session_start();

print_r($_SESSION['foo']);
```

Change this equation to

```
<?php
   // Start our first session with the name 's1'

session_id('s1');
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Foo';
session_write_close();

// Start our second session with the name 's2'

session_id('s2');
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Bar';
session_write_close();

// We now open our first session and print its value
session_id('s1');

session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['foo']);
?>
```

Session_id is an identifier of the session, so it can be different for different session but session_name is just a different name for same session.

Comment: So, there is no way of doing this without changing the session's id? I regenerate the id every other action, so that may be a problem for me.

Comment: @VictorTello, If you are goin' generate the id don't use something simple like s1 or s2 .. because of Cookie Injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

`session_name()` sets the cookie name that's sent to the browser as indicated in the picture.
[image]

php uses an identifier for the session which the value of cookie in the picture. 
which can be changed via `session_id` as indicated by @Amit Ray

Here is another tricky solution, you can change the `session.path` dynamically .. you will have 2 files with the same  identifier in two different folders

Here is the code

```
<?php

session_save_path('/tmp/phpsess1/');
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Foo';
session_write_close();


// Start our second session with the name 's2'

session_save_path('/tmp/phpsess2');
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'Bar';
session_write_close();
//
// // We now open our first session and print its value


session_save_path('/tmp/phpsess1');
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

this would print `Array ( [foo] => Foo )`

Comment: Uhm that seems interesting, thank you, but, to clarify, there is no way of doing this with session_name, right?

Comment: @VictorTello no, you have to use `session_id` or this tricky one above.
But I actually recommend `session_id` as it's more straightforward.

Comment: Yeah I had problems using session_save_path with hhvm... I will use the session_id... Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

There is one way of using the session name (cookie name) for switching between sessions. I am developing a web app that requires this functionality and came up with the following piece of code.

```
/* set the first session name */
session_name($ses->one->name);
/* check if the first session cookie is set and use the value as the id */
if(isset($_COOKIE[$ses->one->name])) session_id($_COOKIE[$ses->one->name]);
/* start the session */
session_start();
/* store data in this session */
$_SESSION['name'] = $ses->one->name;
/* get the session id */
$ses->one->id = session_id();
/* close the session */
session_write_close();

/* repeat the same process for the second session */
session_name($ses->two->name);
/* if you loading the sessions as the same time you will need to assign a different session id to the second session */
if(isset($_COOKIE[$ses->two->name])) session_id($_COOKIE[$ses->two->name]);
else session_id($ses->one->id . '_1');
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $ses->two->name;
$ses->two->id = session_id();
session_write_close();
```

now time to retrieve the data stored.

```
/* set the session name */
session_name($ses->one->name);
/* set the session id */
session_id($ses->one->id);
/* start the session */
session_start();
/* echo out the data */
echo 'session 1 : ' . $_SESSION['name'] . '<br>';
/* close the session */
session_write_close();

/* repeat the same process for the second session */
session_name($ses->two->name);
session_id($ses->two->id);
session_start();
echo 'session 2 : ' . $_SESSION['name'];
session_write_close();
```

I hope this helps some of you out there.